# How to get a data miner to do specific search on web page?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, web-crawler, lxml

I am new to Python and am trying to work with Pattern. My goal is to get a code which will give me the synonym of the input word, after looking it up from the IndoWordnet. The language must be Bengali. I have a list of words already. But I am not sure how exactly, with the help of Pattern I can web-search an input. I have tried following http://arunrocks.com/easy-practical-web-scraping-in-python/ . It didn't help much. I wanted to started with a parsed web page and this is what I did. This ill give us the absolute link too.

```
from lxml.html import fromstring
from urllib2 import urlopen
def get_page(url) :
    html = urlopen(url).read()
    dom = fromstring(html)
    dom.make_links_absolute(url)
    return dom

dom = get_page('http://www.cfilt.iitb.ac.in/indowordnet/first?langno=3&queryword=%E0%A6%97%E0%A6%BE%E0%A6%A7%E0%A6%BE')

<Element html at 0x50b4840>
```

But I am stuck after that as I do not know how to do specific search with pattern. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit more tricky than it seems cos there is an AJAX request that gets the data you want to scrape, so make it in two steps:

- get the special `sid` value corresponding to the word you are looking for (it is inside a `label` with `id` attribute equals to `sid`)
- make another request to the `http://www.cfilt.iitb.ac.in/indowordnet/ajax/onto.jsp` passing the `sid` you've grabbed on the first step. For example, see how it looks for the `sid=4827`: http://www.cfilt.iitb.ac.in/indowordnet/ajax/onto.jsp?sid=4827

Here's the code. It prints all antology labels:

```
from lxml.html import parse
from urllib2 import urlopen

SID_URL = 'http://www.cfilt.iitb.ac.in/indowordnet/ajax/onto.jsp?sid=%s'

url = 'http://www.cfilt.iitb.ac.in/indowordnet/first?langno=3&queryword=%E0%A6%97%E0%A6%BE%E0%A6%A7%E0%A6%BE'
tree = parse(urlopen(url))

sid = tree.find('.//label[@id="sid"]').text

tree = parse(urlopen(SID_URL % sid))
for record in tree.xpath('//ontorecord'):
    print record.find('onto_label').text
```

`UPD` (getting synonyms):

```
from lxml.html import parse
from urllib2 import urlopen

url = 'http://www.cfilt.iitb.ac.in/indowordnet/first?langno=3&queryword=%E0%A6%97%E0%A6%BE%E0%A6%A7%E0%A6%BE'
tree = parse(urlopen(url))

for label in tree.xpath('.//label[@id="words"]/a'):
    print label.text
```

Comment: @user3458145 ok, sorry, misunderstood a bit, since I don't know both hindi and bengali. Check the `UPD` section - should give you all the synonyms.

Comment: @user3458145 I've used chrome developer tools->network tab to see what AJAX calls are going. It's not about python - most of the things are xpath and web-scraping related.

Comment: how to get the "%s" part of the 'http://www.cfilt.iitb.ac.in/indowordnet/ajax/onto.jsp?sid=%s'?

Comment: @user3458145 `%s` is a placeholder for the `sid` - see the code I've provided: `sid = tree.find('.//label[@id="sid"]').text`.

Comment: Maybe, pushing a little too much, but would it be possible to get the synonyms without having to put their url every time?

Comment: @user3458145 well, this is how it works on the web site itself.